# Collapsing Toolbar Layout setting typeface

Tags: android, android-styles, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I realized that I could set the typeface for the title when the toolbar is expanded and collapsed. But it seems like, it will only choose one or the other if I set the text appearance as well.

Here is the text appearnce I am using when the toolbar is collapsed:

```
 <style name="CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/large_text</item>
</style>
```

Here is what the collapsing toolbar layout looks like:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

And in my code I try to do this:

```
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Title");
    collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf"));
    collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf"));
```

It seems to always just choose the font from the collapsing toolbar layout. 
Removing the text appearance properly switches between the two different typefaces. But I cannot control the text size then.

Also note that I did try to set the font in `CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle` with no avail.

Comment: Oh man! Same Problem I have. did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope, lemme know if you do... i am looking into it

Comment: I did the same thing which you have mentioned. It's coming fine in mobile (ASUS Zenfone 5) but not in Tablet (Samsung TabS)

Comment: So this is a device specific issue!? I wam testing mine on the Nexus 5

Comment: Still I couldn't find anyway to successfully make it happen!